Ship Trip data which that shows passenger count?
Could some one please tell me if they know of a source of data that shows past passengers numbers for ships? Its specifically cruise ships the

ROALD AMUNDSEN
Passenger (Cruise) Ship, IMO 9813072

& the
https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/details/9813084[
FRIDTJOF NANSEN
Passenger (Cruise) Ship]2'
I am not seeking capacity but actual passenger numbers in the last few years.
i suspect this is difficult information to obtain for business competition reasons.
Any help would be much appreciated.
